# Bug in FullSimplify

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Studying the generalized sum of the certain divergent series in version 13.1 on Windows 10 by

```
Sum[(-1)^k*(4 k + 1)*2^(2 k)*k!^2/(2 k)!, {k, 0, Infinity},Regularization -> "Abel"]
```

> `HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, -1]`

, I come to the following inconsistent result

```
FullSimplify[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, -1]]
```

> `E^(I Interval[{0, 2 \[Pi]}]) (-\[Infinity])`

The above is in contradiction with

```
N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, -1]]
```

> `-1.`

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Interestingly, `HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, -1] // FunctionExpand` also evaluates to `E^(I*Interval[{0, 2*Pi}])*(-Infinity)` and `Limit[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, x], x -> -1]` evaluates to `-1`

Comment: Interesting, that `Interval` on the answer. Even if it would be correct, shouldn't this simplify to `ComplexInfinity`?

Comment: `SumConvergence[(Pochhammer[1, n]*Pochhammer[1, n]*Pochhammer[5/4, n])/(Pochhammer[1/4, n]*Pochhammer[1/2, n])*((-1)^n/n!), n]` evaluates to `False` and `Sum[(Pochhammer[1, n]*Pochhammer[1, n]*Pochhammer[5/4, n])/(Pochhammer[1/4, n]*Pochhammer[1/2, n])*((-1)^n/n!),
 {n, 0, Infinity}]` also indicates that the sum does not converge.

Comment: @BobHanlon. Thank you. Unfortunately, `Sum[(-1)^k*(4 k+1)*2^(2 k)*k!^2/(2 k)!*x^k,{k,0,Infinity}]` results in `(1/((1 + x)^(3/2)))(Sqrt[1 + x] - Sqrt[x] ArcSinh[Sqrt[x]] - 
  8 x Sqrt[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -x] - 
  8 x^2 Sqrt[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -x])` and `Limit[%, x -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow"]` performs `(Sqrt[2] - ArcSinh[1] - 
 16 Sqrt[2] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -1])/(2 Sqrt[2])`.

Comment: V12.0 gives the same thing.  However, `HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, x] // FunctionExpand`  gives an algebraic answer which returns `-1` when `x=-1`.

Comment: @BillWatts: Can you present that workaround as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is truly a workaround, since your original Sum will not yield a function of x, but for this particular case we can notice that

```
f[x_] = HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4}, {1/4, 1/2}, x] // FunctionExpand

(*8 x (3/(4 (x - 1)^2) + ((2 x + 1) ArcSin[Sqrt[x]])/(
    4 Sqrt[1 - x] (x - 1)^2 Sqrt[x])) - ((Sqrt[x] ArcSin[Sqrt[x]])/
  Sqrt[1 - x] + 1)/(x - 1)*)
```

and

```
f[-1] // N
(*-1.*)
```

Comment: `Sum[(-1)^k*(4 k+1)*2^(2 k)*k!^2/(2 k)!*x^k,{k,0,Infinity}]` results in `(1/((1 + x)^(3/2)))(Sqrt[1 + x] - Sqrt[x] ArcSinh[Sqrt[x]] -    8 x Sqrt[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -x] -    8 x^2 Sqrt[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -x])`  and `FullSimplify[((1/((1 + x)^(3/2))) (Sqrt[1 + x] - 
       Sqrt[x] ArcSinh[Sqrt[x]] - 
       8 x Sqrt[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -x] - 
       8 x^2 Sqrt[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, 3/2, -x]) // 
    FunctionExpand) /. x -> 1]` results in `-1`.